Intellij IDEA maven jar: exclude config files

Create new java maven project in IDEA.
create new file resource/test.txt
add new JAR artifact, check "include in project build"
to exclude resource/test.txt from .jar file, add to pom.xml :


<build>

<resources>
    <resource>
        <directory>src/main/resources</directory>
        <excludes>
            <exclude>*</exclude>
        </excludes>
    </resource>
</resources>

    <plugins>
    <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>3.3.0</version>
        <executions>
            <execution>
                <id>default-jar</id>
                <phase>package</phase>
                <goals>
                    <goal>jar</goal>
                </goals>
            </execution>
        </executions>
        <configuration>
            <excludes>
                <exclude>*</exclude>
            </excludes>
        </configuration>
    </plugin>
    </plugins>

</build>


        
 5. rebuild project

I get untitled1.jar with "test.txt" file inside

So, I want to exclude test.txt file from resulting .jar file, how I have to do it?

Why are you excluding everything from src/main/resources? Are there files inside that directory?

Why have configured the maven-jar-plugin ? Adding it a second time to the life cycle? And excluded everything here as well?
